# How should we prepare for a parent-teacher consultation in preschool?

Tags: education, school, pre-schooler, teacher

Our very first parent-teacher consultation for our pre-schooler (almost three years old) is coming up. Because of that I'd like to bring some more attention to this question:
[How to maximise the usefulness of parent teacher consultations?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/321/how-to-maximise-the-usefulness-of-parent-teacher-consultations)
 which had until now only one answer (albeit an excellent one from HedgeMage), but I would like to make it also more specific about preschool.

In our experience communication between teachers and parents in (this) preschool is quite different from daycare. It's not impossible to have contact with the teacher during the schoolyear but it takes more effort then at our daycare where we regularly had an informal conversation about our child with the caregivers. Altough we have the impression she is doing ok, this lack of communication makes us a bit unsure about what our child does at school, how she behaves and if she feels well. In a way we expect to get more insight in how she is doing.
Altough we have some small comments on how things are going I have no reason at all to distrust the school or the teacher. Still I have some irrational "first child paranoia" and I would like to gain some trust in the school.

I know I can not expect to change all this with this one consultation but still I want to take as much out of it as possible.

Which information should the teacher give us?

What questions should we ask to make sure our child is feeling well at school and is getting the education (as far as education goes at preschool) she needs?

Which questions illuminated things for you, about the time your child spends at school, or exposed aspects of your child you did not know of?

Comment: Having worked in a preschool, I think it's totally appropriate for you to show up unannounced (tho don't let your kid see you as it makes less helpful) and observe your kid and the teachers. Our rooms had big windows into all the rooms for this purpose (they were above the heads of the kids tho so they weren't a distraction to them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the age of 3, I would have thought the things of most interest would be:

- The child's social skills. At 3yo,
  many children still do side-by-side
  rather than interactive playing
- The child's verbal skills. Are they
  clearly understandable?
- the child's emotional maturity. How
  do they handle the day once they've
  been dropped off. How do they handle
  conflict with other kids.

I currently have a three year old in childcare. The questions I regularly ask the kinder teacher are:

- Who does he play with? This gives me
  an idea of how he interacts with the
  other kids plus lets me know whether
  the teacher is paying attention.
- How does he get on with the other
  kids? If there are any issues with
  fighting, this is when it would come
  up.
- How well can you understand him? My
  boy is bi-lingual so will change his
  language to suit the person he's
  talking to. By asking this question I
  get a feeling for how his vocabulary
  is going and it also explains to the
  teacher than he is not speaking
  gibberish, it's just another
  language.

In terms of intellectual development, you should see evidence of that at home. How the child interacts with her toys, how much she gets into books and stories. Does she sing songs she hears from pre-school (eg: my lad sings a mangled version of ABC, something we never taught him).

IMHO: the kid is 3 - as long as she is happy then things are going well.

Comment: "The kid is 3 - as long as she is happy then things are going well." - you are absolutely right, and I think I overreacted a bit, nevertheless: good answer!